# Python & Sqlite3 Changes not saving to database

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using a docker while I develop a web app and I am using an sqlite3 database to store all the data I need.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(path)
c = conn.cursor()
today = str(datetime.today()).split(' ')[0]
c.execute('UPDATE CONTACTS SET lastUpdate="%s" WHERE id=%s;'%(today,conId))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I know the path is correct because I can easily retrieve information. But when I try to execute this function, the changes remain while the docker is still running but when I restart it, the data reverts to what it was previously.

Any ideas as to why this is, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Docker containers do not persist data by default. One way is to use volumes and store data there. Read this: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: From what I understand, I should create a volume linked to my database with the -v flag using a name and the path to the file? Is that all I need or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so to do this I simply added a few lines to the docker-compose.yml file.

```
volumes:
- ./app/database.sqlite3:/app/database.sqlite3
```

which is also the relative path to my database file.
This works perfectly.